# Joomla: disabling iphone and android view for a template

Tags: android, iphone, templates, joomla, content-management-system

I am currently trying to disable the iphone and android view for a specific template within my site. I don't have much experience with joomla but I've been using google to find some answers but so far no luck.

I've tried removing the files 'index-iphone' and 'index-android' from the template xml but on mobile it stills gives and error and doesn't call the 'index' file.

If my question is unclear or you need further details, let me know and i will try my best to be more detailed

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by going to Extensions > template manager. On this page are several tabs but I clicked on 'Mobile' tab. I was then able to disable to iphone and android view.